# form validations using a directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am new to angularJs.... i am trying to write a directive which wraps the input box inside a form tag and followed by a 'div' which includes validation. validation is not working. 
plunker link : [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/70vb9dicoSYITB0Uv4ZX?p=preview)

i am wrapping the input tag using the following code

```
var getHtml = function(){
                return '<div data-ng-show="myform.myfield.$error.required &&myform.myfield.$dirty ">field is required</div>';
              }

    element.attr('name','myfield');
    element.wrap('<form name="myform"></form>');
    element.after(getHtml());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because you didn't compile the `form` element.
Insetead of:

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

You have to:

```
$compile(element.parent())(scope);
```

But that itself would cause an infinite loop of compilations so you have to remove the `cs-options` attribute before that compilation. Also you have to do this in pre compile rather than post compile (i.e. linking phase).

Working example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/hEbRbwPqi64vZ4CNGf5N?p=preview